# Required qualifications or Qualifications required

Tags: past-participles, participles

I have all the qualifications required for the exam.

Or, I have all the required qualifications for the exam.

What's the difference between them?

and where should we place Participle, working as an adjective, before noun or after noun.

Comment: When I think of the prerequisites needed to take certain exams, I think of them as **requirements** not as qualifications.  I consider successfully completing the exam, an indication that you are qualified for something.  I can see, however, how qualifications can be applied to taking the exam.  It's very likely related to the cultural environment of the exam/education.  I would say, *I have met all the requirements for [taking] the exam*, without mentioning qualifications.  This would be understood as indicating you are allowed to take the exam.

Answer (score 1):

a) 'Qualifications required' has the structure: noun-verb
b) 'Required qualifications' has the structure: adjective-noun

In a), the participle would be in on the verb (in front of, or part of the verb). For example,

> Present participle: Qualifications **requiring**

> Past participle: Qualifications **required**

> Perfect participle: Qualifications **have required**

In b), the participle is actually the verb 'required'. The verb has become an adjective, making it a participle (a verbal that functions as an adjective).

Comment: Is there any difference in the meaning of those two sentences?

Comment: No, actually. It's just the structure that's different. Its use may be different though, for example, if the person wants to emphasize the _requirement_, then the person would put the word 'required' first before the word 'qualifications'. But sometimes it won't affect that much at all when it comes to actually speaking (if this sentence's for writing, this may be useful).